# How does Visual Studio 2019 treat Cross-compile linux (target) Static linking?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, g++, static-libraries

I have a Visual Studio 2019 solution, and it contains 2 projects

1. Project A - Lets call it Engine
2. Project B - Lets call it Game

These are Linux projects. So I've set up a linux host to do the compilation. Project A (Engine) is a static library (.a). Project B (Game) is set to output as an Application (.o)

Project B references Project A as a dependency. It also includes source files from project A, so intellisense does not flag any issues with the project before building.

**THE PROBLEM:**

Engine => Builds fine

Game => "Engine.h" No such file or folder.

This issue is obviously happening on the linux machine during compilation with g++. How do I need to reference the (already referenced) static library correctly, so that g++ will resolve the dependency?

Comment: It seems that g++ on the remote machine does not know about the include directory of your Engine. Visual Studio usually creates a lot of log files, one of them should have the g++ command line in it to verify that the `-I` option is set to your Engine's include path. Question: Does your project build on the windows host?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Be sure to include relevant portions of the project file, the compiler command and its output. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Zaiborg I've purposely designed the project to build on a remote machine. I'd need to add the std library to build on the host at least. VS seems to register the project as Linux only - I'm a VS novice, so I'm not sure if it will build on the host. The code is a very simple example, using only `std::cout` examples to get the toolchain running first.

Comment: I think I may have found the culprit. So by default VS sets the `$(RemoteRootDir) = ~/projects` ... This causes parsing issues, and actually creates a ~ folder in the user's root. Setting `$(RemoteRootDir) = /home/${USER}/projects` and `$(RemoteDeployDir) = $(RemoteProjectDir)/bin/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)` for the Static lib Seems to solve path resolution issues and the project now builds.

@Zaiborg To answer your question, yes `-I` was set in the g++ command, thanks for pointing that out. That did help me actually look in the right places to solve the issue :)